# Apache: Rewrite specific missing file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How can i rewrite **missing** files that match

```
/assets/my_file-[a-z0-9*].xap
/assets/my_file-393458974fd0e030a75bd7c08d62e585.xap # example
```

to

```
/assets/my_file.xap
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.xap$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*).xap$ $1.xap [L]
```